# Should the algebra tag be blacklisted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-blacklist

I'll mention the history of the problems with [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) tag, although I think that most people who visit meta regularly know about this.

The problem with [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) was that it was used for different purposes, and to make the tag useful they have to be somehow separated. 
This was discussed [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/) (and also in some related threads) and the 
community consensus was that [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) and [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) should be used instead.

However, the questions which already were tagged [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) had to be retagged manually, one by one. This was a long process but, eventually, all 
of questions using originally this tag had been retagged.

---

The new problem is, that new users, unaware of this, created the algebra tag again and again.

Some solutions have been suggested:

- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/disambiguation-pseudo-tags: Creating some "pseudo-tags" which cannot be used for questions, but they have tag-wiki containing information which tags can be used instead. 
  (This would be a definitive solution of this problem. But we do not know, whether this will be implemented.)
- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/algebra-disambiguation-tag: As a provisional solution [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) was created again, some questions were added to this tag *artificially* (so that the tag is not deleted in the regular [pruning](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/how-liberally-should-we-handle-tag-creation/2829#2829) of empty and low-usage tags)
  and tag-wiki for this new tag contains information that it should not be used. (So the effect is similar as in the suggestion about pseudo-tags, with the exception that we cannot prevent users from applying the tag to questions.)
  Despite the warning given in the tag-excerpt and tag-wiki, a few questions are tagged with this tag every week.
- Synonymize  [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) and [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), as suggested [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/6390#6390).

When discussing [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) tag, the possibility of blacklisting this tag was mentioned a few times in comments, e.g., 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/algebra-disambiguation-tag#comment20076_5074) and 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag#comment13610_3081).

Blacklisting would mean that tag with this name cannot be created again. Again, to some extent, this is similar to "pseudo-tags" with the exception, the user 
trying to apply this tag doesn't see recommendation which tags should be used instead of this tag. Blacklisting seems to be rather extreme option, I quote from
the tag-wiki for [tag-blacklist-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-blacklist-request/info) at meta.SO:

> Tags must be "quite bad" to be blacklisted. Generally, these are tags that could *never* convey any useful information or are actively harmful to the site. Because of the potential consequences of getting something wrong, only the dev team is able to add tags to a site's blacklist.

AFAIK the complete list of blacklisted inputs is visible only to mods. But to mention just a few examples, the tags that have already been blacklisted at MSE include proof (see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/proof-tag-again)), mathematics and equations (see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/the-mathematics-tag)).

---

So the question is:

> - Should we request [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra) to be blacklisted?

---

**EDIT:** At the moment there are 27 votes for and 5 votes against blacklisting this tag. So it seems that the prevailing opinion is that this tag should be blacklisted. I guess the rest is up to our moderators, who can ask SE team to do this.

Comment: If someone knows more about blacklisting, I'd be glad to know how exactly the warning for a user trying to use a blacklisted tag. (I tied to search meta.SO, but didn't find this information.) Or, for that matter, if you know any information that might be relevant for this discussion.

Comment: I would say further that even the abstract-algebra tag is somewhat obsolete. I would prefer the more specific ring theory, commutative ring theory, group theory and field theory tags.

Comment: You get the message "sorry, the 'algebra' tag is not allowed." when you try to create it. To get the tag blacklisted, one of your moderators has to ask an SE community manager to blacklist the tag.

Comment: I would be more in favor if the rejection message could be customized. I'm worried about giving new users the impression that questions about algebra are not welcome.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've asked at meta.SO, it seems that the text of the warning cannot be changed: [Warning when using a blacklisted tag - is it customizable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149588/warning-when-using-a-blacklisted-tag-is-it-customizable)

Comment: you can ask SE admins to black list the tag so no one can recreate it again.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Willie Wong said in a comment [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/algebra-disambiguation-tag#comment20076_5074) that "math", "mathematics" and "equations" are blacklisted at MSE. Yet people still ask questions about solving equations. But I agree that the word *algebra* is slightly different; people are more likely to try to use it as a tag. (I think that only mods can see the list of blacklisted inputs, so the only information I have about them is from comments like that.)

Comment: Should we keep the poll longer? I mean it's quite conclusive already...

Comment: @Asaf Last time we asked SE management to do something (question quotas) it lasted only a week until some MSE users asked to change the decision. So I did not want to be hasty. But as you write, voting seem to be evidently in favor of blacklisting the tag. So I've accepted the answer with more upvotes.

Comment: Martin, it only took a couple of months and a flag! @Shog, thanks!!

Comment: Thank robjohn for cleaning up the last few instances of the tag being used!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

*Please do not downvote this answer*

### YAY!

Comment: Since I cannot vote my own; I vote for this one.

Comment: I upvoted this, because I've long given up on deleting that bloody tag from the questions that keep getting tagged with it... not worth the hypertension.

Comment: Shouldn't you make this CW (as well as the other)?

Comment: @Nate: Should I? There is no reputation gain from meta posts; there is no badges that are awarded/unawarded for votes which depend on CW; I was also posting this from a cellphone... :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that reputation wasn't awarded on meta.  Never mind then.

Comment: There are badges awarded separately for meta though, including at least some badges related to questions/answers.   Asaf, you've got a few recently; and this is the only meta answer you have which appears recent enough to be likely. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila?tab=activity

Comment: @Dan: True, but I would have got those regardless of these answers being CW.

Comment: The negation of *nay* is actually *yea*... Though I can see why someone could be so tired of the continual reappearance of the (algebra) tag that they would simply let out an exclamation of joy instead.

Comment: I wonder who downvoted, and why...

Comment: [Is “yay or nay” an acceptable alternative to “yea or nay”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/817/is-yay-or-nay-an-acceptable-alternative-to-yea-or-nay) at ELU (english.SE)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am sure you know that there are proper English words that might be better here.

Comment: I am considering downvoting for your failure to correct the misspelling!

Comment: @dfeuer: Sure, bumping a solved topic from last year is a great idea. Also, I was quite excited from the idea of the tag being blacklisted, so "Yay!"

Comment: @AsafKaragila, some puns, unfortunately, are too common as misspellings to be recognizable as puns. I'm sorry I jumped into this one, though.

Answer (score 7):

*Please do not downvote this answer*

### NAY!

Comment: Until I started using this site, I had never heard of "algebra precalculus" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precalculus) says it's an American term).  This makes me feel a bit skeptical about blocking "algebra" which is what it's called here (=Australia).

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones: It's not a term used anywhere, it's a disambiguator.

Comment: Now this one has 1 downvoter, too (not me)... Strange, but at least there is the same number of downvoters on both possibilities. (Maybe that was the reason.)

Answer (score 2):

RE: The blacklisting: since a new user attempting to create an algebra tag may be astonished that this math blog has no algebra section, maybe there is a way to handle this through the reputation filter portion of the code: By asking the developers to put an unlimited requirement on the reputation necessary to create the "algebra" tag, and creating a specific info-bubble that says, "please choose either abstract algebra, precal algebra etc" instead of the default "only users with x reputation can create a new tag," the problem could be avoided completely, without the negative side effects.

Comment: I'd say this is very close to the suggestion given at [Disambiguation pseudo-tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/disambiguation-pseudo-tags)

Comment: And certainly [there are other MSE users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6483494#6483494) who would prefer that solution over blacklisting. One of the problem is - your solution needs to be implemented, mechanisms to blacklist a tag already exist.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense that it's been thought of.  I guess I was just trying to join in the convo :)